# How to get information from a barcode in an android app?

Tags: android, barcode

I've looked on StackOverflow however none of them directly show you how to. Sort of just leads you to an endless line of posts. 
I get that you first need to read the barcode and then find the product info with an API. Would anyone have any idea which API could be used for EAN?

Comment: use google vision barcode scanner library and onActivityResult  call api to check product info

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have a framework API to read barcodes. Instead you will need to integrate third-party libraries to your project. The most popular and free ones are next:

[zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

[mlkit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes)

Both libraries have samples teaching how to integrate and use them in your projects.